# Нужна ли запятая при двойном использовании частицы «не» в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частица-не, ссп

*Не я заварил эту кашу(,) и не мне ее расхлебывать!*

*Не я писала эти строки(,) и не мне их исправлять!*

*Не я забеременела(,) и не мне рожать!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Частица ***НЕ*** здесь ни при чём. Все приведёные предложения являются восклицательными, поэтому запятые не ставятся.

> **3.** Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:
> <...>
> **3)** восклицательные предложения: *Как он смешон и как глупы его выходки!* — объединяет восклицательная интонация...

Источник: [**Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133) (Розенталь).

P. S. Если бы восклицательных знаков не было, то запятые перед союзом ***И*** ставились бы по общему правилу для сложносочинённых предложений. Первые части имеют подлежащее и сказуемое, а вторые являются безличными (инфинитивными) – субъект действия обозначен, но стоит не в именительном падеже.

P. P. S. Спасибо, Sharon, за комментарии. На самом деле я бы не стал так однозначно говорить о ненужности запятых в подобных предложениях, поскольку пунктуация в них зависит от степени экспрессии, пауз, ударений, задумки автора. Так что можно поставить запятую и даже тире:
***Не я заварил эту кашу — и не мне ее расхлебывать!***

Comment: Спасибо. Даже не думал, что отсутствие восклицательного знака может влиять на постановку запятой.

Comment: @Sharon  Да. Я сначала написал ответ с необходимостью запятых (можно правку посмотреть, там то же, что и в P. S.) Но потом вспомнил о восклицательных, побудительных и вопросительных случаях и изменил ответ. А сомнения остались, как раз именно из-за тех розенталевских примеров с КАК и подобных.   А зачем вы удалили комментарий?

Comment: Затем, чтобы заменить его :)) Александр, вы уверены, что запятая не нужна? Интонационно там пауза вполне возможно, а в примерах у Розенталя говорится о восклицательных ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯХ, которые ПОСТРОЕНЫ определенным образом. Например, местоимение КАК в них имеет восклицательное значение. (Ну и конечно же, они имеют восклицательную интонацию.) Но даже если предположить, что запятой в приведенных предложениях  нет, то вполне возможно, что именно ПОВТОРЕНИЕ частицы НЕ способствует их объединению в одну фразу. В этом случае мы получаем ОДИНАКОВУЮ СТРУКТУРУ предложений.  Как вы считаете?

Comment: Могет быть, могет быть... Думаю, что в подобных предложениях не очень принципиально отсутствие/наличие запятой. Обе части можно прочитать с экспрессивным восклицательным ударением на ***Я*** и на ***МНЕ*** и считать их однородными (объединенными). А можно прочитать так же, но сделать более длительную (многозначительную) паузу и поставить запятую или даже тире.

Comment: Если поставить ударение, то  и паузу придется сделать, а также нужна будет запятая. И общим элементом здесь может быть только интонация, другого варианта нет. Но вообще вопрос интересный, Розенталь не объяснил его подробно, а самим сложно догадаться. А что он имеет в виду, когда говорит о побудительной (тоже восклицательной) интонации: Подпустить врага и огонь дать по команде!  Наверное, все-таки важна структура предложений. В общем, правило неясное, остается наблюдать за практикой.